# How to improve react native app performance?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, react-native

I've build an lms app in react native.I've used `router-flux` for navigation.Sometimes the app seems to be very slow in performance.Every screen is preforming network requests.But the UI will render without any delay.The issues I'm facing are:

1. When a user clicks on any button within sidebar the navigation will be very slow which will create a bad user experience.I've tried to clear all the `console.log`.But if I keep on using the app continuously it will become very slow in navigation and also `TouchableOpacity` is too slow.
2. Also tried to reduce the app size of app by changing `def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true` ,but that just reduced 1MB.

Is there any solution for the above? Please help.Thank you!

Comment: _But if I keep on using the app continuously it will become very slow_.That sounds like a memory leak

Comment: Oh so how do I resolve the problem?Is there any method?

Comment: have you tested these things in a release build?

Comment: Yes I've.There is a little bit change in performance.

Comment: Regarding memory leaks, i am not an expert in this area but there's plenty of SO questions on that topic :)